# Graphing income/expenses

Tags: graph, google-sheets

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yg5Nvq2vA8n9UDaRSZoHc19aNSMtCtbo5jVLCwExmik/edit?usp=sharing) is a sample of the income and expense table I have. Now I want to generate a graph that will tally up the number by the month and show me how much I get from sell and lose from spend each month.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In "Graph" sheet paste this formula:

```
=QUERY(Income!B:G,"select month(B) + 1, sum(G) where C <> '' group by month(B) + 1 label month(B) + 1 'Month', sum(G) 'My Income'")
```

same formula will count Expenditure. You could also try make Expenditure numbers negative, so you could make single query:

```
=query({Income Range; Exp Range}, "select month(Col1), sum(Col6)...
```